# Android/Java equivalent of App Config/ Web Config

Tags: c#, java, asp.net, android

I'm new to java and android, originally from an asp.net/c# background.
I am looking for a config file in java, similar to the webconfig of app config with .net but there doesn't seem to be one..

Is there an equivalent?

Thanks

Bex

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I am using a coded preference file as I think this is the easiest for now.

Comment: You're not supposed to answer just to accept your own... there's other valuable answers here to accept.

Answer (score 1):

Java desktop-style apps don't have a file like this... and Android apps fall into this category (more or less).  Java does have the Properties API, which can read properties from configuration files.  It also has the Preferences API, which have per-user and per-machine storage facilities.

Android supports both [Properties](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Properties.html) and [Preferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html).

Answer (score 0):

AndroidManifest file is fairly similar.

From http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html

Before the Android system can start an application component, the system must know that the component exists by reading the application's AndroidManifest.xml file (the "manifest" file). Your application must declare all its components in this file, which must be at the root of the application project directory.

The manifest does a number of things in addition to declaring the application's components, such as:

- Identify any user permissions the
  application requires, such as
  Internet access or read-access to the
  user's contacts.
- Declare the minimum API Level
  required by the application, based on
  which APIs the application uses.
- Declare hardware and software
  features used or required by the
  application, such as a camera,
  bluetooth services, or a multitouch
  screen.
- API libraries the application needs
  to be linked against (other than the
  Android framework APIs), such as the
  Google Maps library.
- And more

Comment: I have looked at the manifest, but you can't store custom properties can you? ie custom name value pairs?